# Prove $ \lim_{x\to -\infty } \frac{x+8}{x+3} = 1 $ using only the definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I need to prove this limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to -\infty } \frac{x+8}{x+3} = 1 $$

I started with:

$|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1|< ϵ $

$|\frac{x+8-x-3}{x+3}|=|\frac{5}{x+3}|=\frac{5}{|x+3|} <ϵ$

$\frac{5}{\epsilon} < |x+3|$

How do I proceed from here? how the hell can I extract the expression inside the absolute value? Am I in the wrong direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $x+3\le0{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm sorry I needed to correct it, $x->-\infty$, is it still right?

Comment: Then $|x+3| = -x-3$

Comment: How will you right the inequality with epsilon? cause I didn't quite understand why it's true, can you please elaborate? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac5\epsilon &< \left|x+3\right|\\
\frac5\epsilon &< -\left(x+3\right)\\
x &< -\frac5\epsilon-3
\end{align*}$$
Hence, given $\epsilon>0$, we can take $M= -\frac5\epsilon-3$ such that $x<M$ implies $$\left|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: But how can you say that $\left|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1\right|<\epsilon => \frac{5}{\left|x+3\right|}< -\frac{\epsilon}{5}-3  $ when it's clear that the left side is positive and the right side is not ?

Comment: I didn't say $\frac5{\left|x+3\right|} < -\frac\epsilon5-3$, I said $x < -\frac5\epsilon-3$.

Comment: Ok, if $ M = -\frac{5}{\epsilon} - 3$ I just need to know why $x< -\frac{5}{\epsilon} - 3$ is enough to say that $ \left|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1\right|<\epsilon $

Comment: Yes, because $x$ is a negative number and $x \to -\infty$. So analogous to the $x\to +\infty$ case, for any $\epsilon > 0$, if we can find an $M$ such that all smaller $x<M$ satisfy $\left|\frac{x+8}{x+3}-1\right|<\epsilon$, then we can say that limit is one when $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
(And sorry I'm on my phone)

Given any $ϵ>0$, we want to find $M$ such that
$$
\left|\frac {x+8}{x+3}−1\right|<ϵ
$$
whenever $x<M$.

You have basically already done this.

Try to pick a $M$ that is a function of $ϵ$.